# Restarting chunk job execution with Spring Batch Integration

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch Integration to copy files from a bucket to the local directory and launch jobs which read these files.

I followed this tutorial [Transforming File Into a JobLaunchRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#transforming-a-file-into-a-joblaunchrequest)

If an exception occurs during the processing it's ok, the job is marked as FAILED and when I start the project again the job restarts.

But I'm tried a critical situation, when the server down during the reading.

When I started again I received the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobExecution: id=1, version=1, startTime=2021-02-12 19:47:47.0, endTime=null, lastUpdated=2021-02-12 19:47:47.0, status=STARTED, exitStatus=exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=1, version=0, Job=[receivablePositionJob]], jobParameters=[{input.file.name
```

I verified the logic behind the restarting a job and the problem is that step is marked as STARTED with no END_TIME. Of course I know that this is the correct behavior.

Is there any way to handle that and I force the job to be executed?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Spring integration: the job status and it’s management is clearly Spring Batch matter. Please, be careful when you choose tags for the question

Comment: @ArtemBilan more or less... as I said this is the normal behavior of Spring Batch, what I asked is if there's a way to before job was launched by integration, I could handle, discover if the job already exists, their status and decide what I want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the job/step execution status to `FAILED` as well as the end time to a non null value. Here is a quick example:

```
> update BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION set status = 'FAILED', END_TIME = '2020-01-15 10:10:28.235' where job_execution_id = X;
> update BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION set status = 'FAILED' where job_execution_id = X and step_name='failed step name';
```

The SQL syntax may be different depending on your database server. With that, you should be able to restart the execution.